# How to render json output in Octobercms component

Tags: php, json, laravel, octobercms

At the time I ran into a problem when creating a component for my plugin in octobercms. The problem is when I run the following query:

```
public function onRender(){

    $blogs = BlogPost::where('published', 1)
           ->where('published_at', '<=', 'NOW()')
           ->orderBy($this->property('sortOrderBy'), $this->property('sortOrder'))
           ->with('tags')
           ->paginate($this->property('postsPerPage'));
    $this->blogs = $blogs;
    //print_r($blogs);
}
```

But if I want to display a result of tags that belong to the post in the html of the component with {{}} post. Tags come json output. How can I make sure that I can show the names of the tags?

My component file:

```
{% for post in posts.blogs %}
<p>{{ post.titel }}</p>
<p>tags: {{ post.tags }}</p> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**post.tags** is a collection of tag. More info about collections https://octobercms.com/docs/database/collection

Try this code to browse the tags collection :

```
{% for post in posts.blogs %}
    <p>{{ post.titel }}</p>
    <p>tags:
     {% for tag in post.tags  %}
       {{ tag  }}
     {% endfor %}   
     </p> 
{% endfor %}   
{% endfor %}
```

Could be also {{ tag.name }} or {{ tag.title }} instead of {{ tag  }}